# Lots of inorrect syntax errors along with IDENTITY_INSERT Issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create my first database and it's my first time using SQL Server. The software is a little confusing to me, right now I have a database but when I execute it I get a lot of errors. I tried following a guide but it didn't show any errors when he ran it.

I'm trying to create a database that is a stream website. This is what I have so far: These are my errors: I don't understand any of them, how is my syntax wrong? I've only used Java before so this is all a little overwhelming.

```
      Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
     Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
     Incorrect syntax near 'User_Password'.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
        Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
    Invalid object name 'Content'.
     Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 45
       There is already an object named 'ProfileSettings' in the database.
     Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
     'ProfileSettings' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
 USE master
 GO

 if exists ( select * from sysdatabases where name = 'Detour')
    drop database Detour
    GO

    CREATE DATABASE [Detour]
    GO

    ALTER DATABASE [Detour] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140 
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON [dbo].[orders]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Account (
    UserName INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    User_Password VARCHAR (20),
    GO

    INSERT INTO Account(Username, Password) VALUES ('ReedKinney', 'PASSWORD123')

    CREATE TABLE Content (
    Content_Cycle INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TV VARCHAR(50),
    MOVIES VARCHAR(50),
    GENRES VARCHAR(50), 
    HIGHESTRATED VARCHAR(50)
    GO

    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('ACTION', 'THE WITCHER' , 'BLADE 
      RUNNER', 'SHERLOCK HOLMES')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('CLASSICS', 'TWIN PEAKS', 'TAXI 
     DRIVER', 'THE LONGEST YARD')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('COMEDIES', 'THE OFFICE', 'JUST 
     FRIENDS', 'WATERBOY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('DOCUMENTARIES', 'TIGER KING', 
      'ICARUS', 'ZEITGEIST')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('DRAMAS', 'GAME OF THRONES', 'THE 
    KINGS SPEECH', 'MARRIAGE STORY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('HORROR', 'HAUNTED MANSION', 'HOUSE 
     ON THE LEFT', 'PARANORMAL ACTIVITY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('ROMANCE', 'GILMORE GIRLS', 'HER', 
  'SILVER LNININGS PLAYBOOK')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('THRILLER', 'OZARK', 'SE7EN', 'THE 
     GIRL WITH THE DRAGON TATTOO')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('SPORTS', 'BASKETBALL', 'MONEYBALL', 
   'NACHO LIBRE')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('SCIENCE', 'THE UNIVERSE', 'THE 
    MARTIAN', 'OUR PLANET') 

    GO 

    CREATE TABLE ProfileSettings (
    ProfileName INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LanguageChoice VARCHAR(50), 
    MaturitySetting VARCHAR(50)  )

    GO

    INSERT INTO ProfileSettings (ProfileName, LanguageChoice, MaturitySetting) VALUES('REED', 
    'ENGLISH', 'ALL CONTENT')
    GO
```

Comment: "it's my first time using MySQL" - first decide what database system you're using. Those errors appear to be SQL Server errors, not MySQL (two different product from different vendors)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a decent ide such as ssms which would highlight the errors pretty well. I have corrected the syntax errors and annotated the changes in line. If this was an accurate transcription of code I suggest you get another guide.

```
if exists ( select * from sysobjects where name = 'Detour') --sysdatabases >> sysobjects
    drop database Detour
    GO

    CREATE DATABASE [Detour]
    GO

    ALTER DATABASE [Detour] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140 
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] on --move on to end of statement
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Account (
    UserName INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, --
    User_Password VARCHAR (20) -- remove , 
    )                          -- added 
    GO

    INSERT INTO Account(Username, USER_Password) VALUES ('ReedKinney', 'PASSWORD123') --password >> user_password

    CREATE TABLE Content (
    Content_Cycle INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TV VARCHAR(50),
    MOVIES VARCHAR(50),
    GENRES VARCHAR(50), 
    HIGHESTRATED VARCHAR(50)
    )                           --added
    GO

    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('ACTION', 'THE WITCHER' , 'BLADE 
      RUNNER', 'SHERLOCK HOLMES')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('CLASSICS', 'TWIN PEAKS', 'TAXI 
     DRIVER', 'THE LONGEST YARD')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('COMEDIES', 'THE OFFICE', 'JUST 
     FRIENDS', 'WATERBOY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('DOCUMENTARIES', 'TIGER KING', 
      'ICARUS', 'ZEITGEIST')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('DRAMAS', 'GAME OF THRONES', 'THE 
    KINGS SPEECH', 'MARRIAGE STORY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('HORROR', 'HAUNTED MANSION', 'HOUSE 
     ON THE LEFT', 'PARANORMAL ACTIVITY')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('ROMANCE', 'GILMORE GIRLS', 'HER', 
  'SILVER LNININGS PLAYBOOK')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('THRILLER', 'OZARK', 'SE7EN', 'THE 
     GIRL WITH THE DRAGON TATTOO')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('SPORTS', 'BASKETBALL', 'MONEYBALL', 
   'NACHO LIBRE')
    INSERT INTO Content(GENRES, TV, MOVIES, HIGHESTRATED) VALUES('SCIENCE', 'THE UNIVERSE', 'THE 
    MARTIAN', 'OUR PLANET') 

    GO 

    CREATE TABLE ProfileSettings (
    ProfileName INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LanguageChoice VARCHAR(50), 
    MaturitySetting VARCHAR(50)  
    )
    GO

    INSERT INTO ProfileSettings (ProfileName, LanguageChoice, MaturitySetting) VALUES('REED', 
    'ENGLISH', 'ALL CONTENT')
    GO
```